How do I read a single byte from standard input using built-in commands in a bash script?
I have been trying to make a shell function that reads a byte from the standard input and prints the character code. However, the read command I used seems to interpret any bytes greater than 127 as \0 (null character). Is it possible to write a script to read one byte without skipping bytes greater than 127 without calling any external binaries?
Here is my code:
#!/bin/bash
myfunction() {
  read -rn1 -d '' char || return
  if [ -z "$char" ]; then
    # Runs when "$char" is null, but also when it's greater than 127.
    printf '0'
  else LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$char"
  fi
  [ -t 1 ] && echo
}

Expected result:
$ printf '\x05\x00\x80\x00\x32' | (while myfunction; do :; done)
5
0
128
0
50

Actual result:
$ printf '\x05\x00\x80\x00\x32' | (while myfunction; do :; done)
5
0
0
0
50

What am I doing wrong?
I have also tried read -rN1 char, which skips null characters instead, and -d '' is ignored here.
$ printf '\x05\x00\x80\x00\x32' | (while myfunction; do :; done)
5
128
50

Edit: Adding LC_CTYPE=C to the beginning of the read command fixed it. Thank you for your help.

Can not reproduce. I get the expected result.

What OS and what version of bash? I get 128 and 50. Also, why not add while myfunction; do :; done at the end of your script and then just pipe printf '\x05\x00\x80\x00\x32\n' to it? E.g. printf '\x05\x00\x80\x00\x32\n' | yournewscript.sh

The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

I also get the expected output with the bash version 5.2.37. What version of bash do you experiment with?

Maybe it's a locale problem? Try setting export LC_ALL=C before running your script.

For the record, char="$(head -c1)" should do the job.

@EdMorton Setting LC_CTYPE=C seems to have fixed it. Thanks!
